# Laravel 5 app on Bluemix

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, ibm-cloud

I’ve been having trouble to deploy my laravel app to bluemix using laravel 4.2 and 5.0.
This is the error in the blumix logs:

```
2015-05-01T16:52:49.71+0100 [STG/0] ERR [UnexpectedValueException]
2015-05-01T16:52:49.71+0100 [STG/0] ERR Could not parse version constraint ^1.2.2: Invalid version string “^1.2.2″
2015-05-01T16:52:49.71+0100 [STG/0] ERR install [–prefer-source] [–prefer-dist] [–dry-run] [–dev] [–no-dev] [–no-plugins] [–no-custom-installers] [–no-scripts] [–no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|–verbose] [-o|–optimize-autoloader] [–ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] … [packagesN]
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] OUT —–> Composer command failed
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/scripts/compile.py”, line 51, in
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR .from_build_pack(‘lib/additional_commands’)
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py”, line 189, in extensions
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR process_extension(path, ctx, ‘compile’, process, args=[self])
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py”, line 69, in process_extension
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/extensions/composer/extension.py”, line 359, in compile
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR return composer.compile(install)
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/lib/extension_helpers.py”, line 154, in compile
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR self._compile(install)
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/extensions/composer/extension.py”, line 162, in _compile
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR self.run()
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/extensions/composer/extension.py”, line 244, in run
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR *self._ctx[‘COMPOSER_INSTALL_OPTIONS’])
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/extensions/composer/extension.py”, line 289, in run
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR shell=True)
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR File “/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack/lib/build_pack_utils/runner.py”, line 109, in stream_output
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
2015-05-01T16:52:49.73+0100 [STG/0] ERR build_pack_utils.runner.CalledProcessError: Command ‘<open file '’, mode ‘w’ at 0x28b9420>’ returned non-zero exit status 1
2015-05-01T16:52:49.76+0100 [STG/0] OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
2015-05-01T16:52:50.02+0100 [API/3] ERR Encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

This is where it fails in the composer.lock file:

```
“require”: {
“nikic/php-parser”: “^1.2.2″,
“php”: “>=5.3.3″,
“symfony/console”: “~2.1″,
“symfony/filesystem”: “~2.1″,
“symfony/finder”: “~2.1″
},
```

That `^1.2.2` is what it’s complaining about. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the contents of `manifest.yml`?

Comment: You may want to review [this](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/06/17/getting-started-laravel-bluemix/) post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of the PHP buildpack are you using?  You may want to try it with the latest community release by pushing your app with the `-b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack` option.

I know that with an earlier version of the buildpack (v3.1.0), you actually needed to specify a special attribute called COMPOSER_VERSION in a file that you push with your application called options.json

Example options.json:

```
{
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "fpm", "tokenizer", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "pdo"],
  "PHP_VERSION": "PHP_55_LATEST",
  "COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR":"htdocs/vendor",
  "COMPOSER_VERSION": "latest",
  "WEBDIR": "htdocs/public"
}
```

source: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/47#issuecomment-82972562

More information about this configuration file can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md

Answer (score 1):

Can you run `composer update` locally to make sure your composer.lock is up to date. Also make sure you are not pushing the composer.phar to Bluemix. You can stop any files from being pushed to Bluemix by creating a `.cfignore` file in the root of your code and then adding the name of the file/directory you don't want to upload to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I do have the .cfignore file and I was using v3.1.0 indeed.

Anyway, as a temporary fix, I replaced all the ^ with the >= < corresponding values, altough with newer versions of the buildpack shouldn't be necessary.

Also, the PHP version needs to be wrapped around {} for bluemix to pick it up correctly: "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_55_LATEST}"

Thanks